# Python extract occurence of a string with regex

Tags: python, regex

I need a python regular expression to extract all the occurrences of a string from the line .

So for example,

```
line = 'TokenRange(start_token:5835456583056758754, end_token:5867789857766669245, rack:brikbrik0),EndpointDetails(host:192.168.210.183, datacenter:DC1, rack:brikbrikadfdas), EndpointDetails(host:192.168.210.182, datacenter:DC1, rack:brikbrik1adf)])'
```

I want to extract all the string which contains the rack ID. I am crappy with reg ex, so when I looked at the python docs but could not find the correct use of re.findAll or some similar regex expression.
 Can someone help me with the regular expression?
Here is the output i need : [brikbrik0,brikbrikadfdas, brikbrik1adf]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can capture alphanumerics coming after the `rack:`:

```
>>> re.findall(r"rack:(\w+)", line)
['brikbrik0', 'brikbrikadfdas', 'brikbrik1adf']
```

Comment: The `r"rack:(\w+)"` will also extract alphanumerics after `track:`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew good point, I think Jan addressed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Add a **word boundary** to `rack`:

```
\brack:(\w+)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/iW9dX2/1).

---

In `Python` ([**demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/BveiOn)):

```
import re
string = """TokenRange(start_token:5835456583056758754, end_token:5867789857766669245, rack:brikbrik0),EndpointDetails(host:192.168.210.183, datacenter:DC1, rack:brikbrikadfdas), EndpointDetails(host:192.168.210.182, datacenter:DC1, rack:brikbrik1adf)])"""
rx = re.compile(r'\brack:(\w+)')

matches = [match.group(1) for match in rx.finditer(string)]
print(matches)
```